# Possible to use dataset as ref

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, ado.net, ref

i have multiple dataset that is using on multiple form . so i make the dataset as public and store this on my Mdiparent form . when i open any form i use this call the dataset on child form and bind that dataset with my combobox . There are 20 dataset that are using on the form . So due to this load time take near about 30 - 35 seconds . So i want to use that dataset as `ref` . How can i do this . Below the code that i am using right now

**On Form Parent**

```
  public DataSet dszip = null;
  dszip = _forderdac.GetZipPostal();
```

**On Child form**

```
 DataSet dszip = dsAddr.Copy();
 cmboboxZip.DataSource = dszip.Tables[0];
```

Thanks for your comments and advice.

Comment: An object like `DataSet` is a reference type by definition. You are countering that by calling `.Copy();`. So, if you want to use the reference of the `DataSet`, don't copy it.

Comment: @Adimeus there are multiple combobox is bind from one dataset . so i use `.COPY()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DataSet` is a `Reference Type` by nature. `Value Types` are primitive types like `int`, `bool`, `double`, `long`, etc.

`DataSet` is not the better approch to transfer data. You could use `generics` collections like `List<T>` and create a class (a [`DTO`](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) object for sample) which contains just the properties you need to bind into the form. With this you can get a better performance.

You could be sure if your query itno database to fill this dataSet is good query.

This article explain with some detail why is better using generics collections instead dataset.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163751.aspx